# I am getting an invalid parameter message from xcopy on a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

This is the command I am using:

```
xcopy \k "f:\work\sourcefolder\sourcefile1" "f:\work\targetfolder"
```

Comment: @Kayasax, you should make that comment an answer so it can be accepted and marked as answered.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `/k` instead of `\k`